# Extract Frames of Video at Runtime

Tags: c#, video, barcode

I can find plenty of methods for extracting all frames of a video when it is not playing. However what I want to achieve is extracting frames at runtime while the video plays. I want to be able to scan the video for qrcodes at runtime, but my blocker is extracting the frames while the video plays.

My platform for building this in is Windows and C#.

Looking for any library or strategy to achieve this. The best idea I have so far is have the video playing and extract and scan frames for each N second that the player progress hits. But there must be something better than that.

Comment: Do you need to do it in real-time?

Comment: Yes. An example would be for a demo: watching a live stream, and a qr code appears, and message appears with decoded contents.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tutorial made by Microsoft can help you a little bit.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/get-a-preview-frame

Hope that my answer was helpful for you! :)